# jQuery.css not working for element added with append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using a modular pattern for writing my JS code. I have an object with references to all my dom elements. I have put the selector for a div that I'm adding at a later point in my code execution. When I add that div, and use jQuery.css using the reference I stored in my references object, it doesn't work.

```
NameSpace = {
    objects: {
        someButton: $('.someButton'),
        someDiv: $('.someDiv'),
        myDiv: $('.myDiv'), //This will be added later
        //Other references
        .
        .
    },

    bindHandlers: {
        NameSpace.objects.someButton.on('click', someEventHandler);
        //Other bindings
        .
        .
    },

    eventHandlers: {
        someEventHandler: function(e){
            var div = jQuery('<div class="myDiv"></div>');
            NameSpace.objects.someDiv.append(div);

            //Doesn't work! If I use jQuery('.myDiv'), then it works,
            //but kills my modular style
            NameSpace.objects.myDiv.css({ //some styles });
        },
        //Other event handlers
    }
}
//Other code
```

This approach works fine for objects that exist in the page, but isn't working for a div that I add like above.

Any help?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/myrjY/

there are some differences between 1.9 and 2.0 check out on link

Comment: What kind of differences? I couldn't figure out a thing from your fiddle...

Comment: try switching between versions 1.9 and 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is procedural, this line `myDiv: $('.myDiv')` is computed only once and not everytime you call it.

It means that your selector `$('.myDiv')` is filled at the start of your page.

To resolve this you'd have to make your variable a function

```
objects: {
        someButton: $('.someButton'),
        someDiv: $('.someDiv'),
        myDiv: function(){ return $('.myDiv'); }, //This will be added later
        //Other references
        .
        .
    },
```

It should recalculate the selector everytime you call it.

Let me know if the trick works.

Comment: Tried it man... but it throws an error, and when console logged the objects.myDiv, it show me as a 'function'. Meaning it is getting the function assigned, but not the return value!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Do `objects.myDiv()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Florian, your solution worked! Can I do this for any element that is added dynamically?

Comment: You should do this for every selector (those in your `objects`) of elements that are added dynamically. Doing it for all of them is not a too bad idea either as it'll be less confusing and not much more resource consuming.